# ExtJS 5.1, grid load data from database with PHP

Tags: php, extjs, extjs5

I am doing an online course of Ext JS 5.1 and in this exercise I have a `service.php` file which connects to database and returns JSON Data. I try to show this data but it never gets displayed (doesn't show any error message in firebug) and I can`t find what is the problem with the code.

This is the code of the store:

```
var storeUsuario = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model : 'js.clase.Usuario',
    proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url: 'service.php?method=getUsuarios',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

This is the code of the grid:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        store: storeUsuario,
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        title: 'Grid Usuarios',
        columns: [
            {
                text: 'id',
                dataIndex: 'id'
            },{
                text: 'nombre',
                width: 100,
                dataIndex: 'nombre'          
            },{
                text: 'apellidos',
                dataIndex: 'apellidos'
            },{
                text: 'email',
                dataIndex: 'email'
            },{
                text: 'nacionalidad',
                dataIndex: 'nacionalidad'
            },{
                text: 'rutaAvatar',
                dataIndex: 'rutaAvatar'
            }
 ]
});
```

and the `service.php` method:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    $conexion = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("usertest", $conexion);

        $method = $_GET['method'];

    switch($method) {

    case "getUsuarios":
            $query = "SELECT * FROM Usuario ORDER BY id ASC";
            $result = mysql_query($query, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());

            $numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);

            $usuarios = array();

            if ($numRows > 0) {
                $i = 0;
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                    $usuarios[$i] = $row;

                    $i++;
                }
            }

            $usuariosJSON = json_encode($usuarios);

            echo $usuariosJSON; 
            break;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Does the php code really return something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code doesn't return a valid JSon.

See this fiddle works correctly: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/q9k

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script/4064468#4064468) you should specify the header.
And I suggest you to return a "hand formed" json like this:

```
$data = /** whatever you're serializing **/;
$data_length = /* the length of the result according to the request response */;
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); // just to be sure
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo "{ \"success\": true, \"total\": $data_length, \"records\": " . json_encode($data) . " }";
```

The json data could need `[]`...

```
echo "{ \"success\": true, \"total\": $data_length, \"records\": [ " . json_encode($data) . " ] }";
```